# Controling Android with Arduino (Dpad Input, Home Button, Recent Tasks, Media Buttons...)

Tags: android, arduino, communication, android-permissions, keyevent

I started to investigate how to send via Wifi some commands to control an android device (Nexus 7 - rooted). So I created an UDP Server app in Android that simulates some buttons through KeyEvent class (for the moment I'm trying to send UDP messages from PC via Wifi to test). 
The problem is that it only works within the app, if I open Google Music and I simulate increase volume the app close due to INJECT_EVENTS Permissions.

So at this point I need some ideas to proceed with this project and these are my different options:

- Continue with Wifi communication and try to create a service able to skip system permission to simulate all Android buttons I want.
- Try BT communication - maybe there is a way to communicate directly to the OS instead through an app.
- Try USB communication - I know that through adb shell commands you can simulate all the buttons but...Is it possible to send adb commands from an arduino? Should it be only through USB or could it be via Wifi?

I'm avoiding Tasker/Autoshare solution as it's very slow for what I need.